# calling a function outside of the function call in which it was defined

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to log `myNewFunction()`,and the results shows undefined.

```js
function outer() {
  let counter = 0;

  function incrementCounter() {
    counter++
  }
  return incrementCounter;
}

const myNewFunction = outer();

console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
```

Comment: You are calling `myNewFunction()` but there is no such thing defined in the provided code.

Comment: You need `var myNewFunction = outer();`

Comment: ooops thanks for mention that. there has been some mistake while pasting the code.  the code below is my the  full code.
function outer(){
    let counter = 0;
    function incrementCounter(){counter ++}
    return incrementCounter;
}

let myNewFunction = outer();

console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())

Comment: I have Edited my post
please have a look.

Comment: Why would it show anything else? `incrementCounter` just increments `counter`; it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to log myNewFunction(),and the results shows undefined.

Because `myNewFunction`, which is the same as `incrementCounter` doesn't return anything:

```
  function incrementCounter() {
    counter++
    // no return statement here
  }
```

If there is no explicit return statement, a function returns `undefined`. If you want it to return the new value of `counter` then do that.

```js
function outer() {
  let counter = 0;

  function incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    return counter;
  }
  return incrementCounter;
}

const myNewFunction = outer();

console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
```

Answer (score 0):

As what i am able to get after running your code which shws that the function which you wants to call my myNewfunction that is not defined in that block.
you have to introduce it first and then use it.

{
"message": "ReferenceError: myNewFunction is not defined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 21,
"colno": 1
}

Comment: can you please run the code snippet again. it returns undefined output.

Comment: when i was reading this question i run this code an i got that error now i also get error undefined.

Comment: yes!  i hope you got your answer happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually call the function when passing value. If you want to get counter value. Should return it. Instead of returning incrementCounter() function in your example. I also suggest moving counter to global. To avoid counter resetting every time myNewFunction() is called.

```
let counter = 0;

function outer() {
  function incrementCounter() {
    counter++
  }
  incrementCounter();
  return counter;
}

const myNewFunction = outer;

console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
console.log(myNewFunction())
```

Comment: by not executing the function "outer()" it returns back the incrementCounter function which is not I am after.
I trying to get the value of counter variable.

thanks.